# PHP show content based on referrer

Tags: php

I have this PHP code that shows different content based on referrer but I want to add more referrer sources right now is only Google.com I tried if (strpos($ref,"google.com", "yahoo.com" )>0)  but is not working.

```
$ref=getenv('HTTP_REFERER');
if (strpos($ref,"google.com")>0) 
{
echo "google";

}
else
{
echo "something else";
};
```

Comment: strpos only do one reference, you have to create manual function

Comment: Use an array and `in_array` http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: You have to do multiple strpos checks or use something like preg_match that can handle more than one pattern. Really, you need to check http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php and read the documentation. Knowing how to read documentation is very important.

Comment: You know, you can say `else if (....) { ... }`

Comment: When using strpos, it is better to do a strict comparison against a boolean, since 0 could be a valid position. `strpos` returns `false` if the string is not found. `false !== strpos($ref, 'google')`